# Data persistence on iphone even after reinstall

Tags: ios, iphone, persistence

I got an app that asks for a password. If the user writes their password wrongly three times, then they will be not be able to use the app and if the app is reinstalled, I need to keep this counter alive. 
So if they have entered a bad password three times and reinstall the app, they will be not able to use the app, even after reinstall.

Comment: So how does one reset their password?

Comment: What about if they use the app on the another device? If that is possible. Does this lock them off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a client server set up, then send the device id with the request! Otherwise use the [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: If the apple docs seem overwhelming check out some of the keychain wrappers others have provided. http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/11/13/keychain-wrappers/

Answer (score 0):

Use the keychain. Since the keychain is shared among apps, the values will not be deleted when the app is removed.